# HAproxy a delay between switching, when primary server to come back?

Tags: haproxy

I have Automatic failover and failback configuration HAPROXY:

```
defaults
 mode http
 option http-server-close
 timeout client 20s
 timeout server 20s
 timeout connect 4s

frontend ft_app
 bind 10.0.0.100:80 name app
 default_backend bk_app

backend bk_app
 server s1 10.0.0.1:80 check
 server s2 10.0.0.2:80 check backup
```

How can I implement a delay between switching, when primary server to come back?

Answer (score 0):

On the `server` line, consider adding:

[`rise n`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2-rise) where `n` is the number of consecutive checks required before the server is considered healthy (default 2).

[`inter ms`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2-inter) where `ms` is the interval in milliseconds between consecutive health checks (default 2000).  See also [`fastinter`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2-fastinter) and [`downinter`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.2-downinter), which further modify health check timing when the server is in various states.